# How do I get one to many values in to one row in sql?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to set the following formated value to appear in one row. This is hard for me to explain as I do not know the right term. I am trying to do this in MySQL. I am not able to figure out how can I concatenate to side by side in one row, without duplicating.

[image]

Any guidance or help is highly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by using MySQL [`GROUP_CONCAT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_group-concat) function:

```
SELECT Name,
       GROUP_CONCAT(Mark SEPARATOR ',') AS Marks
FROM tab
GROUP BY Name
```

Check the demo [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=4e73f6b00fe5a193a4fb5b43d4931658).